# Is OOP based on any branch of mathematics?

Tags: oop, math

I know relational databases are based on set-theory, functional programming is based on lambda calculus, logic programming is based on logic (of course :)), and now that I think of it; I'm not sure if imperative and generic programming is based on any particular branch of mathematics either.

Comment: I've heard, that it came from buildings architecture:)

Comment: @hgulyan, no, that's [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern). OOP predates these.

Comment: Logic programming specifically comes from predicate logic.  (There are other types.)

Comment: Objects are finite functions paired with signatures specifying their contracts. Did you check AbdelGawad's recent work on *NOOP*?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OOP does not originate from any strict formalism, but it is a formalism indeed. There were a number of attempts to define that formalism properly. Most notable work is done by Luca Cardelli: http://lucacardelli.name/indexPapers.html (see the whole "Objects" section)

Imperative programming could be based on any Turing-equivalent formalism, including lambda calculus, SK logic, Turing abstract machine, Markov algorithms, or any other similar Term Rewriting System (TRS). Generic programming is not any different, it is a term rewriting system of a sort.

So, for the most common mathematical grounds for literally everything you'd need to dig into term rewriting systems.

A more recent work is AbdelGawad's recent work at Rice University. He builds a mathematical model of mainstream OOP (eg, Java, C#, C++, Scala, X10, etc) called NOOP. Here is a link to his PhD thesis http://scholarship.rice.edu/handle/1911/70199

Answer (score 3):

OOP has its *origins* in programming languages like Simula-67 and Smalltalk-80, rather than any mathematical theory or formalism.  But I suppose that you could say that OOP's object, class and inheritance concepts are *based on* naive or common-sense systems of categories and classification; e.g. the taxonomies developed by Linnaeus.