# The logic and mathematics of object orientation

Tags: oop, math, logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is OOP based on any branch of mathematics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979858/is-oop-based-on-any-branch-of-mathematics)

This is, allegedly, a strange question: are there any mathematical/logic foundations for the object-oriented paradigm? And, if so, is there a paper/book about it?
Thanks.

Comment: This might get better answers at [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It is not a strange question, it is an interesting one! Maybe you could change the tile and leave the prefix away?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979858/is-oop-based-on-any-branch-of-mathematics

Comment: You guys found a duplicate for this?!!  Wow, some of you might be spending too much time on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object oriented paradigm was not derived from a mathematical theory (unlike relational databases), it was initially invented for practical reasons, to simulate processes (Simula). People are trying to find a good mathematical foundation for it so that the existing languages can be polished or moddified, nice theoretical properties can be uncovered and so on.

The work on "Abstract Data Types" is such a train of thought. There are probably other mathematical ways of looking at object orientedness. I found some information in "Object Oriented Software Construction", 2nd edition, Bertrand Meyer.

Answer (score 2):

There are the object calculi studied by Martín Abadi and Luca Cardelli. They have a book, [*A Theory of Objects*](http://lucacardelli.name/TheoryOfObjects.html), and see the "[related work](http://lucacardelli.name/Topics/TheoryOfObjects/RelatedWork.html)" link for the papers.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a lot of work done in this area.  One particular paper I know of is Kathleen Fisher's PhD thesis (I have a [link to her CV](http://www2.research.att.com/~kfisher/cv.pdf) here, but I don't know of a way to get the thesis itself), which I believe laid a lot of the groundwork in this area.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. I'll ask her for it.