# Which branch of computer science focus on object oriented concepts in software?

Tags: oop, computer-science

Is there a branch of computer science that focuses on concepts of OO? There are many books about Object Oriented software development, but they are mostly adopting an engineering perspective.
In the context of a research paper, I'd like to be able to adopt the computer science point of view. In other words, most resources out there seem to be about the craft, not the science behind the craft. 
Important books, papers which study OO at a more abstract level would be really useful.

Comment: There is a very little real science behind that overrated OO thingy. The most important stuff is in the Type theory area, see this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979858/is-oop-based-on-any-branch-of-mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book appears to be a good starting point: [http://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Object-Oriented-Languages-Types-Semantics/dp/026202523X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/026202523X) 
In case anybody else is looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Object Oriented Software Construction by Bertrand Meyer is probably the most in-depth study of OO I've come across.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to check AbdelGawad's recent work at Rice University.  He builds a mathematical model of mainstream OOP (eg, Java, C#, C++, Scala, X10, etc) called NOOP.  Here is a link to his PhD thesis http://scholarship.rice.edu/handle/1911/70199